# How to get data from mbd-select in angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs-directive

I want to get data from mdb-select from the HTML template to component typescript with using forms. 
My HTML is:

```
<mdb-select [options]="optionsSelect" placeholder="Select Transaction" class="colorful-select dropdown-primary custom-input" (change)="getValue($event)"></mdb-select>
```

My Component is:

```
optionsSelect: Array<any>;
this.optionsSelect = [
    { value: '1', label: 'Transaction 1' },
    { value: '2', label: 'Transaction 2' },
    { value: '3', label: 'Transaction 3' },
    { value: '4', label: 'Transaction 4' },
    { value: '5', label: 'Transaction 5' },
    { value: '6', label: 'Transaction 6' }
]

//get data of select from the html
getValue(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Please suggest which event should I use to get the options values from the mdb-select into my component. I have used (change) event-handler but it is not working the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use selected event

```
<mdb-select [options]="optionsSelect" placeholder="Select Transaction" class="colorful-select dropdown-primary custom-input" (selected)="getValue($event)"></mdb-select>
```